# Knockout.js: how do I get registered component instances?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I get an instance of a registered component with knockout.js? Specifically, for a component like this:

```
ko.components.register('create-feature-request', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        var self = this;
        self.title = ko.observable();
        self.description = ko.observable();
        self.clear = function() {
            self.title("");
            self.description("");
        }
    },
    template: { require: 'text!static/knockout-templates/create-feature-request.html' }
});
```

I want to be able to call a viewModel method, like this:

```
component1.clear();
```

I know about using a [shared object instance](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-shared-object-instance), but it wouldn't work if I needed to access more than one instance of the component:

```
component1.clear();
component2.clear();
```

Is there anything built in to knockout that I can tie into? I can write my own component creation callbacks to get instances as a hack, but I *really* want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get [the entire binding context that was available to the DOM element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) which include [$component context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) that you can use to invoke your methods.

```js
ko.components.register('create-feature-request', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        var self = this;
        self.title = ko.observable();
        self.description = ko.observable();
        self.clear = function() {
            self.title("");
            self.description("");
        }
    },
    template: '<div><input data-bind="value: title"></input></div>'
});

function vm() {
  this.clear = function() {
    let component1 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("component1").children[0]).$component;
    let component2 = ko.contextFor(document.getElementById("component2").children[0]).$component;
    component1.clear();
    component2.clear();
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<create-feature-request id="component1"></create-feature-request>
<create-feature-request id="component2"></create-feature-request>
<button data-bind="click: clear">Clear</button>
```